# SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/csh_v3.sql"

Tags: oracle, database-schema, oracle12c

I am trying to install the `sales_history` [sample schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html), but I'm getting errors:

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/csh_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/lsh_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/psh_v3.sql"
```

How can I resolve this issue? The `csh_v3.sql` has full permissions,

Full session output:

```
SQL> @?/demo/schema/sales_history/sh_main.sql

specify password for SH as parameter 1:
Enter value for 1: password

specify default tablespace for SH as parameter 2:
Enter value for 2: users

specify temporary tablespace for SH as parameter 3:
Enter value for 3: temp

specify password for SYS as parameter 4:
Enter value for 4: password

specify directory path for the data files as parameter 5:
Enter value for 5: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/sales_history/

writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 6:
Enter value for 6: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/log/

specify version as parameter 7:
Enter value for 7: v3

specify connect string as parameter 8:
Enter value for 8: localhost:1522/techfuturepdb.elom.tg


Session altered.

DROP USER sh CASCADE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected


old   1: CREATE USER sh IDENTIFIED BY &pass
new   1: CREATE USER sh IDENTIFIED BY password
CREATE USER sh IDENTIFIED BY password
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01920: user name 'SH' conflicts with another user or role name


old   1: ALTER USER sh DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs
new   1: ALTER USER sh DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
old   2:  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
new   2:  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users

User altered.

old   1: ALTER USER sh TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
new   1: ALTER USER sh TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp

User altered.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.

Connected.

Grant succeeded.

old   1: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY data_file_dir AS '&data_dir'
new   1: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY data_file_dir AS '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/sales_history/'

Directory created.

old   1: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY log_file_dir AS '&log_dir'
new   1: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY log_file_dir AS '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/log/'

Directory created.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.

Connected.

Session altered.


Session altered.

SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/csh_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/lsh_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/psh_v3.sql"
```

Comment: This is clearly an Oracle issue so I removed the sql server tag.

Comment: Looks you need to replace that manually: [see here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/install-sample-schemas). Not sure why the README doesn't refer to that...

Comment: The script output and error message doesn't tell us much without being able to see the code (unless it's some standard Oracle script available online, in which case a link would help).

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Basically before installing the sales_history schema, you must open the sh_main.sql file and replace __SUB__CWD__ in __SUB__CWD__/sales_history/lsh_&vrs with the path to the csh_&vrs, lsh_&vrs, psh_&vrs. After replacement, you should have something that looks like below: 

DEFINE vscript = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/sales_history/csh_&vrs

DEFINE vscript = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/sales_history/lsh_&vrs 

DEFINE vscript = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/sales_history/psh_&vrs

Comment: @Jerome - please don't edit your question with the resolution (or put it in comments) - add an *answer* explaining what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I just renamed the directory and it worked as expected:

```
mv db-sample-schemas-19.2 "__SUB__CWD__" ;

sqlplus system/Welcome1@node3/pdb1 @"__SUB__CWD__"/mksample.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to follow the instructions in [Oracle's README.md for the sample schema](https://github.com/oracle-samples/db-sample-schemas/blob/main/README.md) which says to run perl to substitute the pwd for __SUB__CWD__

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's#__SUB__CWD__#'$(pwd)'#g' *.sql */*.sql */*.dat
```